# how to create folder view in pyqt inside main window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to implement a folder viewer to view the structure of a specific path. and this folder view should look like a the tree widget in PyQT , i know that the file dialog can help , but i need to have it inside my main window.

i tried to implement this using QTreeWidget and i used a recursed function to loop inside folders, but this is too slow. since it needs to recurse around huge number of folders.
is this the right way to do it? or there is a ready qt solution for this problem.

Check the figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use models and views.

```
"""An example of how to use models and views in PyQt4.
Model/view documentation can be found at
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html.
"""
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QColumnView, QFileSystemModel,
                         QSplitter, QTreeView)
from PyQt4.QtCore import QDir, Qt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Splitter to show 2 views in same widget easily.
    splitter = QSplitter()
    # The model.
    model = QFileSystemModel()
    # You can setRootPath to any path.
    model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
    # List of views.
    views = []
    for ViewType in (QColumnView, QTreeView):
        # Create the view in the splitter.
        view = ViewType(splitter)
        # Set the model of the view.
        view.setModel(model)
        # Set the root index of the view as the user's home directory.
        view.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir.homePath()))
    # Show the splitter.
    splitter.show()
    # Maximize the splitter.
    splitter.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
    # Start the main loop.
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: is it possible to just get the listView of files in a folder (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283851/how-to-display-list-of-files-in-a-specified-directory-using-pyqt5)

Answer (score 12):

for PyQt5 I did this function :

```
def load_project_structure(startpath, tree):
    """
    Load Project structure tree
    :param startpath: 
    :param tree: 
    :return: 
    """
    import os
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeWidgetItem
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
    for element in os.listdir(startpath):
        path_info = startpath + "/" + element
        parent_itm = QTreeWidgetItem(tree, [os.path.basename(element)])
        if os.path.isdir(path_info):
            load_project_structure(path_info, parent_itm)
            parent_itm.setIcon(0, QIcon('assets/folder.ico'))
        else:
            parent_itm.setIcon(0, QIcon('assets/file.ico'))
```

then i call it like this :

```
 load_project_structure("/your/path/here",projectTreeWidget)
```

and i have this result :
[image]

Comment: I believe you forgot to define `projectTreeWidget`

Comment: Yes sorry   projectTreeWidget = self.projectTreeWidget which is a QT widget refference : 

  <widget class="QTreeWidget" name="projectTreeWidget">

Comment: Dear @Softmixt how can we get clicked item path from QTreeWidget?

Comment: Just found the answer! Thank you. https://github.com/Gordarg/gordarg.github.io/commit/1e39b3befc6cd090881a8c82887c0b09c586ce5a?diff=split

Comment: I revive this old answer as I don't catch how to use the missing part ' projectTreeWidget = self.projectTreeWidget'. can you clarify where it should go to make it works please ?

Comment: "self.projectTreeWidget"  is a reference to "QTreeWidget" component defined in your ui file under <widget class="QTreeWidget" name="projectTreeWidget"> tag
so the code will be : 



`

projectTreeWidget = self.projectTreeWidget 
load_project_structure("/your/path/here",projectTreeWidget)

`