# How to Display List of Files in A specified directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfilesystemmodel

How to display in a ListView manner files in a directory specified in the code in a PyQt window

example : Like in the right pane of this QFileSystemModelDialog app

[image: Like in the right pane of this QFileSystemModelDialog app]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to create 2 `QFileSystemModel`, one will show the directories and the other the files. To change the view of the `QListView` you must use the clicked signal, using the `QModelIndex` you set the new `rootIndex`.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        hlay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.treeview = QTreeView()
        self.listview = QListView()
        hlay.addWidget(self.treeview)
        hlay.addWidget(self.listview)

        path = QDir.rootPath()

        self.dirModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.dirModel.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.dirModel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs)

        self.fileModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot |  QDir.Files)

        self.treeview.setModel(self.dirModel)
        self.listview.setModel(self.fileModel)

        self.treeview.setRootIndex(self.dirModel.index(path))
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))

        self.treeview.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self, index):
        path = self.dirModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.setRootPath(path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: can we iterate through the listview ? and retreive all files in a list for a given folder ?